# Database Security and Encrypting

Tags: database, security

I have a quick question based on database security.

I am looking to make a page that will require login details and once granted access will allow the user to change things such as name, address, phone number etc.

As long as the username and password is properly secure the information in the following pages will be safe right?

There is nothing I have to do like encrypting that information because it is behind the wall which is the login area. Or, are there other ways people can access database that I will need to consider?

Also can someone point me in the direction of a good way to do encryption. I have looked at using md5. Is that the best/easiest way to encrypt password and sensitive information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: "*As long as the username and password is properly secure the information in the following pages will be safe right?* 
and
Q: "*Also can someone point me in the direction of a good way to do encryption. I have looked at using md5. Is that the best/easiest way to encrypt password and sensitive information.*"

A: No, web security is not that simple.  For example, an SQL injection bug will allow somebody to retrieve your whole database, including the "encrypted" [sic] information and non-encrypted information.  But the standard way of storing password information is not by using "encryption" but instead some type of hashing (terminology differs from place to place, I'll get to that more in a moment).

As for how to do this properly, the two best sources are:

- [CrackStation.Net](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

  [Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846/)

I'm partial to Thomas Pornin's description, as he is a real cryptographer who understands the issues better than anybody else.  He has a number of posts about this on StackOverflow: you can can Google for it (I can't post more than 2 links since I am a new member here).  Note also the Pornin points out the terminology abuse that everybody is making on this subject ("encryption", "key derivation function", etc...).

Please, please, don't make the mistake of using MD5!

Q: *"Or, are there other ways people can access database that I will need to consider?"*

A: An excellent book on this subject is Cryptography in the Database: the last line of defense.  Think about: where are you backups stored -- how secure are they?  Can system and database administrators always be trusted?  What happens if there is some type of vulnerability in your system (such as SQL injection or remote file inclusion) that allows an attacker to get inside information?  What about the threat of physical data theft?  How about development staff -- do they get access to the database?

So really, it is not an easy question, and it takes a considerable amount of study to get a realistic understanding of the issues.  Your company should have a security architect to help analyze your system and develop the right solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

At the most simplistic level if you code something like `select <columns> from <table> where <key columns> = <verified name>` then yes, only the values matching the login will be displayed.  However, the Bad People will look for ways to get data by going around your application, not by using it, up to and including stealing the [DB server itself](http://royal.pingdom.com/2008/07/18/forget-about-hacking-your-servers-might-get-stolen/).  You need to understand the whole variety of risks you face and make a call on what you're willing to do to address each, and which you are willing to just accept.